# How to load .features file using python?

Tags: python

I have  features extraction dataset .In this dataset I have some folder and every folder contain many file(**.features**) more than 500. Now , I want to read a folder one by one and also want to convert all file(.features) into **CSV** format.

Example of file(.features):

```
JCD:3.0,3.5,6.0...
Tamura:3.608455882352941,6.681779104634786,632.0,130.0...
ColorLayout:11.0,25.0,9.0,4.0,16.0...
EdgeHistogram:0.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,4.0...
AutoColorCorrelogram:13.0,13.0,12.0,12.0,13.0,13.0,12.0...
```

Every file(.features) contain same keyword like JCD , Tamura .. etc

Please mention your code how can i read a folder and convert all files(.features) into csv or excel.

Comment: Try looking at [How to convert a feature class attribute table to csv using arcpy?](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/how-to-convert-a-feature-class-attribute-table-to/td-p/651316)